# GPU memory allocation for different graphics cards not the same

Tags: opengl, rendering, gpu

I'm using `AMD Radeon HD 6000 series` It supports `Open GL 4.1`. Using the below code i'm allocating memory on my GPU for faster processing reasons:

```
glGenBuffersARB(1, &Id[0]);
enm =  glGetError();

glBindBufferARB(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER_ARB, Id[0]);
enm =  glGetError();

glBufferDataARB(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER_ARB, 1920*1080*3, NULL, GL_STREAM_DRAW_ARB);
enm =  glGetError();

guibuffer[loop] = (UINT8*)glMapBufferARB(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER_ARB, GL_WRITE_ONLY_ARB);
enm =  glGetError();
```

Later on `guibuffer` buffer i perform YUV to RGB conversion and render it using opengl.

The rendering is perfect for the above mentioned graphics card. However, when i try the same code on `NVidia GEFORCE 310 GT218`, i get a **white screen** in the rendering window. The open GL versions supported this graphics card is `openGL 3.2`.

Can anyone suggest what is it that is causing the problem? Is it the version of opengl supported by both the graphics cards are different, or the memory allocation method is different for different versions.

Comment: Don't use `…ARB` functions in a OpenGL-3 or later context. Buffer Objects have been core ever since.

Comment: @datenwolf: Can you please please suggest some alternative. Please i have been stuck in this and have no idea regarding how to proceed. Please provide some link or concept.

Comment: Just use the core Buffer Object functions. They're named just like the ARB ones, but without the `…ARB` at the end. The same goes for the tokens used. I.e. `glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, …)` instead of `glBindBufferARB(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER_ARB, …)`.

Comment: This may be a stupid question, but I see nowhere in your code where you ever unmap your buffer... are you actually doing this? It is an error to use a PBO that is still mapped, and the behavior at run-time is ***undefined*** (the spec. only states that an error must be generated, not what happens if you choose to ignore the error).

Comment: Why do you relate this problem to memory allocation ? Couldn't be another part of your program ? shader related maybe ?

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: I have performed the unmapping also. I just want to know that if the memory allocation is causing some problem.

Comment: @rotoglup: The shader version is also same. Only thing is that the DirectX versions are different. ie Nvidia is using 9.0c and AMD is using 11.0

Comment: @datenwolf: Thanks for the suggestion, i tried without _ARB but same problem. This white screen problem is only in nvidia. Any other gusses??